# Can I configure shortcuts for tex commands in Texworks?

Tags: texworks

I was using Kile editor for my tex files but it's too heavy for my laptop... It's very slow. So I installed TeXworks wich is better. But I was very used to command shortcuts in Kile that I don't find anymore in TeXworks.

Like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> for `\textbf{}` etc.

Is there a way to configure them or I should type all the commands?

Comment: I don't think you can create shortcuts like that, but TeXworks does have some code completion features. For `\textfb` you can type `bf` and hit the Tab-key once or twice. See https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/CodeCompletion and Appendix A in the manual written by Alain Delmotte (Help --> A Short manual for TeXworks, or http://www.leliseron.org/texworks/).

Comment: You can, as @TorbjørnT. says, alter the shortcuts for existing commands. You can also use scripting to add in additional commands: there are a couple of examples in Scripts -> LaTeX Styles and these cover bold and italic.